# problem with floated divs in ie6 and ie7

Tags: php, css, html, css-float

i m trying to create a search form and this is it's html code :

```
<div id="search_form">

<div class="form-content">

    <form action="http://localhost/mozaic_site/news/search" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">                            <div class="text-form">

            <input type="text" name="search_text" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" size="50" class="search_text" />                            </div>

        <div class="button_from">

            <input type="submit" name="search" value="بحث في الموقع" class="search_button" />                            </div>

    </form>                        
</div>
```

and this is it's css code:

```
#search_form {
float:right;
border: 1px solid #C1CAD2;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
margin-top:1em;

}
.form-content {
padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.22em 0.22em;
background: url('../images/images_collection_3.png') repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #fff;
height: 2.1em;
position: relative;
}

.button_from {
float:right;
background-color: #FCC530;
border: 1px solid #BD9E43;
margin-right: 0.3em;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
}

.search_button {
background: url('../images/images_collection_1.png') repeat-x right -1672px;
border: 0 none;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
height: 1.8em;
overflow: visible;
font-size: 108%;
}

.text-form {
float:right;
}
.search_text {
height: auto;
width: 30em;
border-color: #7B7B7B #7B7B7B #CBCCCE #CBCCCE;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
height: 1.5em;
padding: 0.3em 0.2em 0.33em 0.25em;
}
```

now my problem is in ie6 and ie7

ie6 make the #search_form div width 100% and ie7 make the form content go out the #search_form div

i tried to discover the problem but i didn't succeed

how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can't you post the remaining code or a link? The problem is that some settings may be inherit from other page elements where that piece of code is child of... Some word of advice regarding IE6, if you need to support it, give proper settings to your elements, just like a width, margin, etc...

Comment: the pages are in my local server so i can't put a link to them

Comment: until now i solved this problem by putting width:40em; for the #search_form any better solution

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML example you gave us is somewhere in the middle of the page it could be because of a missing `</div>`.  You also may not have copied it, so maybe not.

More likely though is your `#search_form` div is floated, thus out of the normal flow of the doc, but your `.form-content`, and others, are not.  Perhaps this is confusing IE?

Try floating your `.form-content` div.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I know of is to add this line of code to your `head` (Assuming all other HTML is correct and this is a css issue only)

```
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="YourStyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/><![endif]-->
```

Then in `YourStyle.css` edit the css to make the work for IE7 only. This will not affect other css as it will not be read unless IE 7 is the brower

I'm 95% sure that it works for IE 6 also `[if IE 6]`

Comment: Well if the issue was with the HTML then it usually is safe to assume that it won't work on most browsers. From what I have experienced if I ever have an issue with something like IE7, but everything works fine on all other browsers, then it is a css issue (which sounds like what your having from the question)

Comment: ok thank i checked the page mode looks like it is in standard mode not in quirk mode so i will use the conditional style sheet do you have any idea how to fix this css to work for ie6 and ie7

Comment: Not of the top of my head, but I could take a look at it if you could send me a link to the page, Though I think the IE 7 issue has to do with the positioning of the `form` with respects to where the content inside the form is. Those kind of issues usually occur with IE 7 and not on other browsers

Comment: IE has supported conditional comments for like...ever (seriously, I think IE 3 or 4 started it), so yes, it will work with IE6. So, for example, if you want to do styles for IE6 and IE7 in the same stylesheet, you can do `[if lte IE 7]`